# Issue : Login with facebook

Tags: facebook, yii

This is my first time to try integrate my page with facebook login. I using the way shown in http://www.domagojsalopek.com/Details/Create-a-Registration-and-Login-System-using-Facebook-Registration-Plugin/21.

I did exactly the same as in the tutorial. I even downloaded the sample and tried, yet it did not work.

But once I filled in all the detail and clicked the 'Register' button, it went to 'Server Error' page. I found that the error came from the following line in register.php

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => FB_ID,
  'secret' => FB_SECRET,
));
```

Note: I had replace my ID and Secret in config.php.

Comment: Are you working on your local host or online (on the URL specified on your facebook app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the solution already. In the sample code it does not include the facebook.php.